# How do I populate the Watermark property on ModelMetaData?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, modelmetadata, data-annotations

I've just finished reading http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html In the article Brad lists the `Watermark` property but there is no mention of which DataAnnotation is used to populate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no annotation supported by MVC 2 out-of-the-box that will set this property.  In MVC 3, it will be settable via `[Display(Prompt = "...")]`.

If you want to use DataAnnotations4 attributes (like [Display]) in MVC 2, you need to use [MVC Futures AspNet4](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742).  See http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/27/localization-in-asp-net-mvc-2-using-modelmetadata.aspx for an example of how to hook everything up.